# How do I duplicate a file stored in ActiveStorage in Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I have a model that is using ActiveStorage:

```
class Package < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :poster_image
end
```

How do I create a copy of a Package object that contains a duplicate of the initial poster_image file. Something along the lines of:

```
original = Package.first
copy = original.dup
copy.poster_image.attach = original.poster_image.copy_of_file
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Update your model:

```
class Package < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :poster_image
end
```

Attach the source package’s poster image blob to the destination package:

```
source_package.dup.tap do |destination_package|
  destination_package.poster_image.attach(source_package.poster_image.blob)
end
```

Comment: I found i also had to have the dependent option set to false to avoid having the blob deleted if the original package was removed:     `has_one_attached :poster_image, dependent: false`

Comment: Yes! Sorry for forgetting that.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this doesn't create a copy of the file. It just makes it so both records point to the same file. Also it will leave the file on the storage system even if all records associated with the file get destroyed.

Comment: Actually, are you sure this is up to date? I just tried it. It seems like `ActiveStorage::PurgeJob` does `SELECT  1 AS one FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."blob_id" = 55 LIMIT 1` and doesn't delete the blob if there are other attachments referring to it. So `dependent: false` shouldn't be necessary?

Comment: I'm referring to [this before destroy](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/bfd296dda797e597e8a54709d1cd331cdffaa9f7/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb#L36-L38).

Comment: There is a before_destroy hook on Blob: `raise ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey if attachments.exists?`

Answer (score 22):

If you want a full **copy** of the file so that both the original record **and** the cloned record have their own copy of the attached file, do this:

In Rails 5.2, grab [this code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/lib/active_storage/downloader.rb) and put it in `config/initializers/active_storage.rb`, then use this code to do a copy:

```
ActiveStorage::Downloader.new(original.poster_image).download_blob_to_tempfile do |tempfile|
  copy.poster_image.attach({
    io: tempfile, 
    filename: original.poster_image.blob.filename, 
    content_type: original.poster_image.blob.content_type 
  })
end
```

After Rails 5.2 (whenever a release includes [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/ee21b7c2eb64def8f00887a9fafbd77b85f464f1#diff-3fd88ddd945ad24c4bd6f76c64c8790a)), then you can just do this:

```
original.poster_image.blob.open do |tempfile|
  copy.poster_image.attach({
    io: tempfile, 
    filename: original.poster_image.blob.filename, 
    content_type: original.poster_image.blob.content_type 
  })
end
```

Thanks, George, for your original answer and for your Rails contributions. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, the second part is still not released in a Rails version besides master.

Comment: Works and I prefer it over [the solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66356098/5925094), because directly attaching the image without opening before ends up being 90% flaky when running all tests.

Comment: With the other solution I was getting a `ActiveStorage::FileNotFoundError: ActiveStorage::FileNotFoundError` on almost every run.

Comment: With this solution I'm getting a IOError when the whole thing is wrapped inside of a ActiveRecord transaction, so it also has its drawbacks.

Answer (score 11):

Found the answer by looking through Rails's tests, specifically [in the blob model test](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-stable/activestorage/test/models/attachments_test.rb#L267)

So for this case

```
class Package < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :poster_image
end
```

You can duplicate the attachment as such

```
original = Package.first
copy = original.dup
copy.poster_image.attach \
  :io           => StringIO.new(original.poster_image.download),
  :filename     => original.poster_image.filename,
  :content_type => original.poster_image.content_type
```

The same approach works with `has_many_attachments`

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :images
end

original = Post.first
copy = original.dup

original.images.each do |image|
  copy.images.attach \
    :io           => StringIO.new(image.download),
    :filename     => image.filename,
    :content_type => image.content_type
end
```

Answer (score 8):

It worked for me:

```
copy.poster_image.attach(original.poster_image.blob)
```

Comment: why is this not the top answer? :)

Answer (score 7):

In rails 5 [Jethro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55288019/4425420) worked well. For Rails 6 I had to modify to this:

```
  image_io = source_record.image.download
  ct = source_record.image.content_type
  fn = source_record.image.filename.to_s
  ts = Time.now.to_i.to_s

  new_blob = ActiveStorage::Blob.create_and_upload!(
    io: StringIO.new(image_io),
    filename: ts + '_' + fn,
    content_type: ct,
  )

  new_record.image.attach(new_blob)
```

Source:

- [Rails 6 Active Storage tests](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-0-stable/activestorage/test/models/attached/one_test.rb#L297)
- [Blob tests](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/734bb308ed198bdf279113fbc1900e75713989ae/activestorage/test/test_helper.rb#L52)

Comment: Works as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

A slight variation on Benjamin's answer did work for me.

```rb
copy.poster_image.attach({
    io: StringIO.new(original.poster_image.blob.download), 
    filename: original.poster_image.blob.filename, 
    content_type: original.poster_image.blob.content_type 
  })
```

Comment: Thank you! This extended version with filename and content_type worked for me

Comment: I prefer Benjamin's solution because directly attaching the image without opening before ends up being 90% flaky when running all tests, I'm getting a ActiveStorage::FileNotFoundError: ActiveStorage::FileNotFoundError on almost every run.

Answer (score 0):

One more approach where we don't have to download and re-upload the file and if your `service` supports copy API (for example: AWS has [copy-object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/copy-object.html)),

```rb
original_blob = original.poster_image.blob

cloned_blob = ActiveStorage::Blob.create_before_direct_upload!(
  filename: original_blob.filename.to_s,
  byte_size: original_blob.byte_size,
  checksum: original_blob.checksum,
  content_type: original_blob.content_type
)

YourS3CopyService
  .new(bucket: cloned_blob.service.bucket.name)
  .copy(original_blob.key, cloned_blob.key)


class YourS3CopyService < ActiveStorage::Service::S3Service
  def copy(key, new_key)
    client.client.copy_object upload_options.merge(
      copy_source: "#{bucket.name}/#{key}",
      bucket:      bucket.name,
      key:         new_key
    )
  end
end
```

It follow same approach as activestorage does for direct-upload without having to download files on the server.